# How to make a TIFF transparent in Java using JAI?

Tags: java, image, transparent, tiff, jai

I'm trying to write a TIFF from a `BufferedImage` using Java Advanced Imaging (JAI), and am unsure of how to make it transparent. The following method works for making PNGs and GIFs transparent:

```
private static BufferedImage makeTransparent(BufferedImage image, int x, int y) {
    ColorModel cm = image.getColorModel();
    if (!(cm instanceof IndexColorModel)) {
        return image;
    }
    IndexColorModel icm = (IndexColorModel) cm;
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    int pixel = raster.getSample(x, y, 0);
    // pixel is offset in ICM's palette
    int size = icm.getMapSize();
    byte[] reds = new byte[size];
    byte[] greens = new byte[size];
    byte[] blues = new byte[size];
    icm.getReds(reds);
    icm.getGreens(greens);
    icm.getBlues(blues);
    IndexColorModel icm2 = new IndexColorModel(8, size, reds, greens, blues, pixel);
    return new BufferedImage(icm2, raster, image.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
}
```

But when writing a TIFF, the background is always white. Below is my code used for writing TIFF:

```
BufferedImage destination = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
Graphics imageGraphics = destination.getGraphics();
imageGraphics.drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, backgroundColor, null);
if (isTransparent) {
    destination = makeTransparent(destination, 0, 0);
}
destination.createGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);
TIFFImageWriter writer = new TIFFImageWriter(new TIFFImageWriterSpi());
writer.setOutput(ios);
writer.write(destination);
```

I also do some metadata manipulation later as I'm actually dealing with GeoTIFF.   But still the images are white at this point.  While debugging, I can view the `BufferedImage` and it is transparent, but when i write the image, the file has a white background.  Do I need to do something specific with TiffImageWriteParam? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: From the research I've done so far, it appears they do though. I also have examples of transparent tifs

Comment: Hmmm.. Why do you draw the source to the destination twice (and create two `Graphics` contexts along the way)?

Answer (score 0):

TIFF has no option of storing transparency info (alpha channel) in the palette (as in your `IndexedColorModel`). The palette only supports RGB triplets. Thus, the fact that you set a color index to transparent is lost when you write the image to a TIFF.

If you need a transparent TIFF, your options are:

- Use normal RGBA instead of indexed color (RGB, 4 samples/pixel, unassociated alpha). Just use `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` or `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`, probably. This will make the output file bigger, but is easy to implement, and should be more compatible. Supported by almost all TIFF software.
- Save a separate transparency mask (a 1 bit image with photometric interpretation set to 4) with the palette image. Not sure if it supported by much software, some may display the mask as a separate b/w image. Not sure how this can be achieved in JAI/`ImageIO`, might require writing a sequence and setting some extra metadata.
- Store a custom field containing the transparent index. Will not be supported by anything but your own software, but the file will still be compatible and displayed with the white (solid) background in other software. You should be able to set this using the TIFF metadata.